# Calling API with application load balancer and Cognito authorization doesn't work

Tags: api, request, token, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

I've build an API which works perfectly fine without authentication. The setup is my own domain, redirected to the application load balancer which forwards the traffic to multiple target groups for my separate API endpoints in different EC2 containers. The application load balancer is setup with https, the certificate is a valid certificate of my domain and so far everything works.

Now I want to add Cognito to the application load balancer. I've already configured a Cognito user pool and an app client, which I can also set in the load balancer without any errors (so the app client settings seem to be right - OAuth Flows, Scopes etc.).

[image]

If I login in my react native frontend with

```js
amplifyService.Auth.signIn({
        password,
        username: email,
      }).then((user) => ...
```

I get back the current user with id_token, access_token etc.

But now the problem:
When I try to call a url of my API with an Authorization header including the `access_token` I got from login in I get the error `Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND customDomain.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com`. I got this error from Postman. When I call the url from my react native frontend I just get `Error: Network error`.

I tried deleting and adding the `customDomain` from the error above in Cognito as a Domain name in the App integration settings, but in both states (with and without the domain) the error occurs.

When I just type in the url of my domain/API endpoint (eg. `https://www.example.com/user/getSettings`) into the browser, I see the redirected url that postman tries to reach (`https://customDomain.auth.eu-central-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?`) and the message, that the site can't be reached.

What could be the problem? Do I have to change some settings? I have tried everything that came to mind, but nothing helped.

I would really appreciate help.